# RISCV tests seem to have no code in start_pc

Tags: testing, riscv, program-counter

I've cloned [this repo](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tests) and built tests using toolchain.

But faced some issues:

1. [riscv-qemu](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu) faults running these tests (segfault or memory allocation fault). Followed the instruction [on your site](https://riscv.org/software-tools/riscv-qemu/)
2. starting pc in the test header (ex., *rv32(64)mi-p-csr*) is set to 80002000, but there is no code in this place (section .tohost)

Can you explain me how to fix this?
Currently on RISCV v1.9 as latest avaliable